# How to prove the monotonicity of this function?

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am trying to prove that the following function is an increasing function
$$
f(x) = \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left(\exp(-\frac{4+4x \cos \theta}{\sigma^2}) \frac{I_0(\frac{2\sqrt{x^2 + 4x \cos \theta + 4}}{\sigma^2})}{I_0(\frac{2x}{\sigma^2})} + 1\right) d \theta
$$
where $\sigma$ is a positive constant,  $I_0(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$.

I used Matlab to compute the function numerically. The results are shown below.

I have been working on this problem for one week but have no idea. Can anyone provide any thoughts on this problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so... the logarithm is taken on the sum, not the exp() solely.

Comment: Whoops: I didn't notice the $+1$.  Sorry.